# How to edit my website

Tags: html, asp.net, css, web-hosting, public-html

I have designed a website using HTML5 and now want publish it. But that website previously was built in ASP.NET. Now I want to upload my data, but there is no "public_html" folder. So how to upload my data??

Comment: it's `www` not `public_html`

Comment: Some hosts have a public_html folder to place your files inside.

Answer (score 1):

Some hosts have a public_html folder to place your files inside while others do not. Just connect to the server and upload them to the folder like usual.